# Select and Upload multiple images with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I am working on an application in which I have to upload multiple images. I am using `redux-saga` and `Nexjs`. Right now it is uploading a single image but selecting multiple images.

My Code:

```
const inputFile = React.useRef(null);

const onChangeFile = event => {
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
var image = event.target.files[0];
if (image) {
  var temp = URL.createObjectURL(image);
  onImageSelect && onImageSelect(temp);
  set_disabled(true);
  dispatch(
    post.uploadImage({
      fileObject: image,
      callback: source_url => {
        imageHandler(source_url);
        set_disabled(false);
        event.target.value = null;
        onImageUploaded && onImageUploaded();
      },
    })
  );
}
};
```

and **JSX**:

```
<>
  <input
    accept='image/*'
    type='file'
    ref={inputFile}
    style={{ display: 'none' }}
    onChange={onChangeFile}
    multiple
  />

  <Box clone color='#666'>
    <IconButton
      size='small'
      onClick={() => {
        inputFile.current.click();
      }}
    >
      <WallpaperOutlinedIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</>
```

Which changes do I need to add to upload multiple images I ama bit confuse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get all the files from the array and try to upload each of them:

```
var images = event.target.files; // Will contain all the images
for(const image of images) {
  // image is single image object
  // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: it is selecting multiple images but uploading only one after the loop

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the rep to reply to your comment directly, but in regard to the other answer here, use Promise.all() instead of a for loop.